# Equivalent of allow_failures from Travis CI for Azure

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

Travis CI has a feature called allow_failure: https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/customizing-the-build/#rows-that-are-allowed-to-fail

They are builds that are allowed to fail  without affecting the status of the entire build. I want to know if there is an equivalent of that in Azure Pipelines ? This is useful for us to test the nightly builds of the compiler.

Answer (score 4):

Set the "Continue on Error" flag on the task that you're anticipating periodic, non-critical failures. That will make the build status "partially succeeded", and allow subsequent activities to run.

Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema?view=vsts&tabs=schema#job